# How to improve this assembly language code so i can include 10 numbers?

Tags: assembly, branch, x86-16

I wrote this code to find maximum element from the an array of 3 elements. What would you guys suggest to change in the code so that i can include 10 elements?

I've tried many alterations but cant figure out how to get the maximum element for an array of 10 elements.

```
[ORG 0x100]

jmp start
num: dw 10,20,30
max: dw 0

start: mov ax,[num]
   mov bx,0
   mov [max],ax

add bx,2
mov ax,[num+bx]
cmp ax,[max]
jl next
mov [max],ax


next: add bx,2
mov ax,[num+bx]
cmp ax,[max]
jl end
mov [max],ax

end: mov ax,0x4c00
int 0x21
```

Comment: You will need a loop.

Comment: without using a loop, how would i implement it? I want just jump statements

Comment: Without a loop you'd need to duplicate your check-if-greater-than-max-and-set-as-new-max block 7 more times.

Comment: A loop is just a compare and a conditional branch instruction, like you already have. It’s just that there is a backward branch instead of only forward branches.

Comment: As this is probably an assignment, to show an example would in essence be doing the assignment for you, but a hint would be, use push for as many iterations as you need.

Comment: @Shift_Left: `push`??  How is that helpful?  You don't need any stack space or static storage for this, just 9x checking the current max (in a register) against the current element.  Using static storage (like this code is doing for no reason) just complicates the code, and using `push` would complicate it more.

Comment: @Jester yes! thats what i was trying to do but where do i duplicate it? in the next or start block?

Comment: The `next` block needs to be duplicated so that each block goes to the, erm, next :)  So maybe use better names such as `check2nd`, `check3rd` and such.

Comment: @Jester THANK YOU!! that worked! i shouldve figured that out, i feel so silly! thanks a tonne, good sir.

Comment: @Jester oh and you should post that comment as my answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score -2):

Agreed, my comment was less than forthcoming, but to be any more informative is to actually do the exercise, so here it is and it is definitely not complicated.

```
    mov     si, Data
    xor     cx, cx
    mov     dx, Crunch

Crunch:
    lodsw
    test    ax, ax
    jz      Exit
    push    dx
    cmp     cx, ax
    ja      Exit
    mov     cx, ax
Exit:
    ret                  ;Either turns to another iteration or terminates

Data:   dw       4, 7, 21, 32, 208, 18, 44, 92, 244, 61, 108, 11, 0
```

This is dynamic, so it will just keep crunching data until zero. Technically this is a loop, but at least not in a conventional sense where there is a specific instruction that would force a move up in code.

Comment: You just using `push Crunch` / `ret` as an obfuscated way to loop, instead of `jna Crunch`.  That's still a loop, not recursion (because you never go more than 1 level deep) and either way I wouldn't recommend this to anyone, especially not a beginner.  Also, apparently this returns the unsigned max in CX?

Comment: @PeterCordes What in the question leads you to believe the values should be signed? I never implied I was attempting recursion, so why bring it up as it's very obvious it is not. Instructing a state machine to do what you want it to do, unconventional or not is not obfuscation. OP criteria was `without a loop`, `jna Crunch` is a looping instruction in this case.

Comment: I was mostly surprised that you were returning in CX instead of the normal AX without commenting the code at all.  But now that you mention it, on 2nd look the OP is using `jl next`, signed compare.  Anyway, if the OP doesn't want to loop, 10 iterations isn't much to fully unroll.  Or explain that conditional branch instructions can loop, which is what I think they're supposed to be doing.  I think the "without loop" is a misunderstanding on the OP's part, not a formal requirement of their assignment.

Comment: Also, yes I know you aren't using recursion, but this is still essentially a loop (despite your claim it's not).  If you want to do this without a loop, and don't want to fully unroll, recursion is the other major technique in computer science for dealing with arbitrary problem sizes.  You are avoiding a backwards conditional branch, but the OP was never specific about what they could/couldn't use.  Again, this is clever but is a poor example for anyone to learn from unless you very carefully lay out why you're doing it this way, and showing the normal loop version of it would be good.

Comment: Thanks @Shift_Left, i appreciate your answer but like Peter remarked, this goes way over my head as im an absolute beginner :)